# Web request error the underlying connection was closed error in VBA selenium

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to run basic below code with the help of selenium driver.

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
End Sub
```

But I Am facing **Web request error the underlying connection was closed error** , Please find the below screen shot of the error.

[image]
Please guide me ho can i make my macro error-free.

Comment: This may occur with outdated chromedriver. Ensure you have latest installed.